# How to convert python text string to List?

Tags: python, string, list

Trying to convert a string in `csv` to `list` item

Here it is what I am trying:

```
txt = "east2,east3"

x = txt.split()

print(x)
```

Tried the below as well, still get same result:

```
txt = "east2,east3"

x = txt.split(", ")

print(x)
```

Output:

```
['east2,east3']
```

Expected:

```
['east2','east3']
```

Comment: Why not using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to load CSV file?

Comment: Try txt.split(","); though the `csv` library should be useful

Comment: yeah tried `x = txt.split(", ")` but still same result

Comment: Try doing this: `list(map(str.strip, txt.split(",")))`

Comment: `txt.split(',')` correct, `txt.split(', ')` incorrect in this context.

Comment: @asp you did `", "` but since you don't have spaces between your items, it won't split it. You'll have to use `","`

Comment: You try to split on `, ` but can't you see that space is not in your input?

Comment: thanks all both` x = txt.split(',')` `x = list(map(str.strip, txt.split(",")))` both ways works, but would like to know is which is best out of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
txt = "east2,east3"

x = txt.split(',')

print(x)
```

result

```
['east2','east3']
```

Comment: Perhaps `str.strip` would also be useful to account for spaces before/after the comma?

Comment: Arvin, do you mean str.strip shall remove extra space if my strings has empty space ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
x = txt.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `split()` method of strings is used to convert the input into lists based on the argument passed.

For **example**:

```
inp="2 3 4"
lis=inp.split()
print(lis)
```

The **output** is:

```
[2,3,4]
```

The default argument for `split()` is `space` or `" "`

When we change this:

```
inp="2,3,4"
lis=inp.split(",")
print(lis)
```

The **result** is:

```
[2,3,4]
```

Thus your code can be :

```
txt = "east2,east3"

x = txt.split(",")

print(x)
```

This will give the desired **output**:

```
['east2','east3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey You are doing a small mistake in `txt.split()`

You are doing

```
x = txt.split(", ")# here you are giving an extra space
```

Corrected code

```
x = txt.split(",")# remove the extra space
```